# SoftEther, unable to ConfigGet

Tags: softether

I have logged in as an administrator of a Hub:

`"Connection has been established with VPN Server "localhost" (port 443).
You have administrator privileges for Virtual Hub 'VPN' on the VPN Server."`

However, ConfigGet command returns:

`"ConfigGet command - Get the current configuration of the VPN Server
Error occurred. (Error code: 52)
Not enough privileges."`

**Does anybody know what is wrong?**

I use:
Unix
Linux ip-172 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

SoftEther
Version 4.18 Build 9570 (English)
Compiled 2015/07/26 15:19:27 by yagi at pc30

Answer (score 2):

I should have set a password on the VPN server itself firstly:

`./vpncmd localhost /SERVER /CSV /CMD ServerPasswordSet server-password`